# How to get Spring Boot Actuator LdapHealthIndicator running with Ldap from Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, spring-boot-actuator

I'm developing a spring boot 2.3 application using spring security. Authentication and authorization is done via spring security against an AD. So I'm using spring-security-ldap and the following code.

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {
...
    public AuthenticationProvider adAuthenticationProvider() {

        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider =
            new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapDomain, ldapUrl);
        adProvider.setSearchFilter(ldapSearchFilter);

        adProvider.setAuthoritiesMapper(authorities -> {
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> gaCollection = new ArrayList<>();
            for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
                if ("admin".equals(authority.getAuthority())) {
                    gaCollection.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Role.ADMIN));
                }
            }
            return gaCollection;
        });
        return adProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(adAuthenticationProvider());
        auth.eraseCredentials(false);
    }

}
```

The relevant dependencies should be this:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
...
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End Spring -->
...
    </dependencies>
```

This works fine.

Now I decided to use Spring Boot Actuators via spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency for application monitoring.

Via auto config it detects the actuator for my data source and the LdapHealthIndicator. While datasource is ok, the LdapHealthIndicator always reports the following error.

```
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT (only LDAP lines)

positive matches:
   LdapAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.ldap.core.ContextSource' (OnClassCondition)

   LdapAutoConfiguration#ldapContextSource matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   LdapAutoConfiguration#ldapTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   LdapHealthContributorAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapOperations' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator management.health.ldap.enabled is true (OnEnabledHealthIndicatorCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapOperations; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'ldapTemplate' (OnBeanCondition)

   LdapHealthContributorAutoConfiguration#ldapHealthContributor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: ldapHealthIndicator,ldapHealthContributor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

negative matches:
   EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryDirectoryServer' (OnClassCondition)

   LdapRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository' (OnClassCondition)
```

```
o.s.b.actuate.ldap.LdapHealthIndicator   : LDAP health check failed
org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: localhost:389; nested exception is 
javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:389 
[Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
```

My AD is running on a remote server and not localhost. Spring security is working fine.

So why does the LdapHealthIndicator try to validate ldap server on localhost? What is the designed way to let LdapHealthIndicator use my `AuthenticationProvider` from my `SecurityConfiguration`?

Comment: Have you already declared your `spring.ldap` properties? Spring Security doesn't use these, but actuator does. For example, what do you have set for `spring.ldap.url`?

Comment: I tried with spring.ldap.url=ldaps://server.domain.tld but the actuator probe ist still localhost:389

Comment: I wonder if your dependencies are correct. For example. spring-security-ldap doesn't depend on spring-ldap, where LdapOperations is declared. Could you share what you believe are the relevant dependencies you've included in your pom?

Comment: I added the relevant dependencies. Anything I should fix there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could possibly be other issues; however, the primary problem appears to be that you are missing [the `spring-ldap-core` dependency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap) from your pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Including this will place it on the classpath. In combination with the correct properties, Spring Boot's LDAP auto-configuration will engage.

Also, [the reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-ldap) state that the property is `spring.ldap.urls`, so I believe it should be changed to that instead.

Comment: I'm sorry. That did not do the trick. I added the dependency and spring.ldap.url to my application.properties. But the  actuator probe is still localhost:389

Comment: No problem. The next thing I'd do is use the `--debug` program argument and confirm that the appropriate Spring Boot Actuator auto-configuration classes are getting invoked. If they aren't, the debug output is usually sufficient to tell you why.

Comment: I added the ldap relevant debug output to my original post. But I still don't understand why it does add the ldap actuator but is not able to validate the server connection but uses localhost. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. I've added a link to the reference docs, which may point out another issue with your configuration.

Comment: The "s"? Oh really? You're great. With spring.ldap.urls it finally works. Many many thanks.